# Execute different actions in sync mode

Tags: c#, helper

I want to create a helper class for action managing.

Suppose we have a set of methods like:

```
void MyMethod(type1 param1, type2 param2, ..., Action finishedCallback);
```

I would like to create a class that executes given methods in a synced way.

```
// var method1 is MyMethod1(int p1, string p2, c => {Console.WriteLine("m1 finished");})
// var method2 is MyMethod2(float p1, string p2, object p3, c => {Console.WriteLine("m2 finished");})
class Parameter
{
   public object Type {get; set;}
   public object Value {get; set;}
}

var actions = new List<Tuple<Action, List<Parameter>>>();
actions.Add(new Tuple<Action, List<Parameter>>(method1, m1Params));
actions.Add(new Tuple<Action, List<Parameter>>(method2, m2Params));
```

How to execute my actions?

```
foreach (var action in actions)
{
   // ???
}
```

**[edit]**
Sorry, forgot it... I want also sync those actions, because they can be executed in async and some of them must be executed in specified order.

So if we have `method1` and `method2` I would also provide something like:

```
MyMethod1(p1, p2, c => {
                          MyMethod2(p1, p2, p3, c => {/* etc. if more */});
                       })
```

Comment: This is over complicating things. Why not offer an overload accepting parameters? like `Action<T>`, `Action<T1, T2>` etc?

Comment: Because it's a 'framework' helper and it can be used by many ppl inside one company. Sometimes the we can have 0-2 params, sometimes 10. I wanted to find a smarter solution for this:)

Comment: If someone is passing a method 10 arguements, he should encapsulate them and pass 1. I think giving an overload taking `Action<T1...T5>` ought to be enough for anyone.

Comment: Can't you add a reference to "dependency" action in the tuple and inside your helper sort whole collection of actions based on dependencies?

Comment: Good idea to handle execution order :) thanks

Comment: What about using the  `myAction.DynamicInvoke(object[] parameters)`   where myAction is a `Delegate`/`Action`

Comment: Didn't hear about `DynamicInvoke`, but it suppose to be what I'm looking for. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Can you convert your comment into an answer? If I got it to work, I would be able to mark the answer as a solution.

Comment: I checked `DynamicInvoke` out. It's what I need, but it's extremely slow. I hope there is another method. In other case I will be forced to use it

Answer (score 2):

Using `DynamicInvoke` will resolve the method at runtime and that is very slow,
why don't you pass the responsibility of defining the parameter to the caller.

```
var actions = new List<Action>()
actions.Add(new ()=> MyMethod1(p1, p2, c => {}));
```

This will resolve the method at compile time and make the function faster.
That you just iterate like this.

```
foreach(var acc in actions) acc();
```

I believe this will be much faster

Comment: The problem is (I think), I can't handle my "**[edit]**" case. If `MyMethod1()` comes from some context that executes it async, there can be a problem (e.g. it's some service's method). I would like to get all the service calls and execute them in some specified order where each one has to wait for another to finish. The problem is I have some mechanism, that cannot be currently changed and I need a synchronizer like this to execute actions synchronously:S

Comment: I think you can do a var asyncAcc = acc as Action<Task>; and if it is not null do .Wait(); I didn't check so try and see if it works.